# Google Chrome: css('text-decoration') returns "extra" values

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

During the development of my website, I notice a strange behavior displayed by Chrome: when I execute a css('text-decoration') query, the returned value also contains some extras, like this:
[image]

This does not happen with Firefox or IE:

[image]

Does anyone know the cause?

Comment: browser interpret css in its own way, or another possibility inspector tool of chrome is different from firefox and IE, might be they does not show this info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of Chrome (31) supports the extended `text-decoration` property as defined in the Candidate Recommendation [CSS Text Decoration Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/). According to it, this property is now a shorthand for `text-decoration-line`, `text-decoration-style`, and `text-decoration-color`. What you see are the values of these properties. You can see them also if you use developer tools (F12) in Chrome and, inspecting an element, select the “Computed” tab (which contains computed values for CSS properties).

The reason why the color is `rgb(105, 105, 105)` in your case is that this is the color of the text (value of the element’s `color` CSS property), and that’s what `text-decoration-color` property defaults to. And `solid` is the initial value of `text-decoration-style`.

Firefox does not currently (in version 25) support that definition, but is has the same functionality implemented, just with a prefixed name. You can see this e.g. by adding `-moz-text-decoration-color: red`.

IE does not even in its newest version (11) support these features but sticks to the CSS 2.1 definition of `text-decoration`.

Answer (score 0):

WebKit/Blink implement additional features of the `text-decoration` property, allowing you to define these additional values.

[Here](http://www.abinader.com.br/2012/08/01/webkit-css3-text-decoration-properties-preview/) is some more information about what they support.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there's some optional values for that attribute.
see [that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style)